# Backbone.js model.get() not work

Tags: backbone.js

In below code, when i want to use get() method as seen in code return undefined. what's the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Views: {}
    };
    window.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
})();

//Model
App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/users'
});

var user = new App.Models.User();
user.fetch({
    success: function (user) {
        console.log(user.get('firstname'));
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the value given to the `success` callback isn't a Backbone model, it's jsut the raw server responsse. To display the first name as soon as the data is fetched, you can use a deferred (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/):

```
var user = new App.Models.User();
$.when(user.fetch()).done(function(){
  console.log(user.get("firstname");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Example is working for me here it is http://jsfiddle.net/YYM43/

Try to see if you have loaded the libs (Backbone.js ...) correctly.

```
(function() {
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Views: {}
    };
    window.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
})();

//Model
App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'http://echo.jsontest.com/name/betty/age/22'
});

var user = new App.Models.User();
user.fetch({
    success: function (user) {
        console.log(user.get('age'));
    }
});
```